# Como criar uma view com crosstab no SQLITE via Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

Tenho as seguintes tabelas:

```
┌──────────────┐  ┌──────────────┐   ┌─────────────────────────────┐
│ TABLE pessoa |  | TABLE lente  |   | TABLE pessoa_lente          |
├──────────────┤  ├──────────────┤   ├─────────────────────────────┤
│ _id, NAME    │  │ _id, COLOR   │   │ _id, idpessoa, idlente, qty │ 
├──────────────┤  ├──────────────┤   ├─────────────────────────────┤
│ 1, "mary"    │  │ 1, "BLACK"   │   │ 1, 1, 1, 50                 │
├──────────────┤  ├──────────────┤   ├─────────────────────────────┤
│ 2, "juan"    │  │ 2, "BLUE"    │   │ 2, 1, 3, 30                 │
├──────────────┤  ├──────────────┤   ├─────────────────────────────┤
│ 3, "jose"    │  │ 3, "GRAY"    │   │ 3, 1, 4, 25                 │
├──────────────┤  ├──────────────┤   ├─────────────────────────────┤
│ ...          │  │ 4, "YELLOW"  │   │ ...                         │
└──────────────┘  ├──────────────┤   └─────────────────────────────┘
                  │ 4, "YELLOW"  │
                  └──────────────┘
```

E preciso obter o seguinte:

```
[crosstab]
NAME   | BLACK | GRAY | YELLOW
"mary" | 50    | 30   | 25
...
```

**Nota Importante:** Não se trata de `join`. Gostaria de uma `crosstab`, recurso conhecido em outros bancos, como PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2):

Olha, pelo que vi até agora do `SQLite` não existe uma forma de trabalhar com o `crosstab`, ou algo parecido, pois uma característica marcante do gerenciador de banco é sua simplicidade, o que o tornou um banco de dados leve, fazendo com que o Android dê suporte nativo a ele.
O único lado negativo do `SQLite` é que foi retirado e/ou não implementado um monte de recursos legais que tem em outros gerenciadores de banco de dados. Já no caso de `crosstab` são muito poucos gerenciadores de banco de dados que possuem essa ferramenta.

Ao meu ver você vai ter que tratar esse tipo de dados pelo app e não pelo banco.

Comment: Para ser bem sincero, como trabalho com gerenciadores de banco de dados robustos como o PostgreSQL, com o SQLite me sinto um confeiteiro com apenas açucar como matéria-prima para produzir toda gama de possíbilidades de sabores. O SQLite **NÂO** tem um monte de coisas que me faz sentir seguro ao usar banco de dados, invés de criar um texto plano como _bando de dados_ . Recentemente, por exemplo, descobri o caso do tipo Boolean(não nativo?!) e a cada dia tenho mais surpresas.Não acho que coisas essenciais a um banco deva ser descartada em preferência a leveza.